# apache installation on aix server

Tags: apache, aix

We are installing **apache 2.4.X** , tried installing

- **2.4.16**
- **2.4.25**
- **2.4.29**

in AIX 7.1 (7100-05-01-1731).

We are facing below issue while we are executing make install for httpd-apache.

We have successfully installed

- apr (apr-1.5.2)
- apr util (apr-util-1.5.4)
- pcre (pcre-8.33).

**Flags that were used are :**

```
export OBJECT_MODE=64
export CC="xlc_r -q64"
export lt_cv_path_NM="/usr/bin/nm -B -X64"
export AR="ar -X64"
```

**Error Stacktrace:**
    we are facing issue that says that  mod_authn_file.so cannot be created due to some error.

```
 rm -f /home/u980868/apache/kiran/httpd-kiran/modules/mod_authn_file.so
 /home/u980868/apache/kiran/httpd-2.4.25/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=install install mod_authn_file.la /home/u980868/apache/kiran/httpd-kiran/modules/

find: bad status-- /home/u980868/apache/kiran/httpd-kiran/modules/mod_authn_file.so

install: File mod_authn_file.so was not found.

make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 2.
```

Comment: Have you successfully compiled `apr-1.6.3` and `apr-util-1.6.1` before `httpd-2.4.29`? These three have to use the same _layout_.

Comment: yes we have. we are able to install them properly without any errors.

Comment: So you have problems with `make install`. Hopefully you saved the logs of `make all` which creates files `modules/aaa/mod_authn_file.la` and `modules/aaa/.libs/mod_authn_file.so`. If you don't have these files, you might have had problems in `make all` too. PS: Hopefully you used linker-flag `-brtl` at every step. ( cf http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html#Q0020 )

Answer (score 1):

If the apache compilation with "make" goes well and you are getting error when you run "make install" the problem may be related to the lack of "coreutils". You can download it for free from http://gnome.bullfreeware.com and install it via "rpm -ivh coreutils-8.25-1.aix6.1.ppc.rpm". Then, first of running "make install" you need to

```
export PATH=/opt/freeware/bin:$PATH
```

It worked in my case.